# How to split cell by character count and comma

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with many data in one column, like this

| Cell | Text |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | R485,R486,R487,R488,R606,R607,R608,R609,R648,R649 |
| A2 | R650,R651 |

I want to find the character count >40 and change to this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8TAu.png)

| Cell | Text |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | R485,R486,R487,R488,R606,R607,R608,R609 |
| A2 | R648,R649 |
| A3 | R650,R651 |

The character count in each cell must be <40, split by "," and the data in a new cell must start with a letter, not only "R" in my data.

Comment: "=LEFT(A1,40)" would return the first 40 characters. Then you could add TEXTSPLIT() and TEXTJOIN().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: [NOT update w/ latest requirement]

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim arr, i As Long, brr
    Dim res(), j As Long, sTxt As String
    Dim k As Long, sTmp As String
    j = 1
    arr = Range([A1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        sTxt = Trim(arr(i, 1))
        If Len(sTxt) >0 Then
            If Len(sTxt) < 40 Then
                ' character count < 40
                ReDim Preserve res(0, 1 To j)
                res(0, j) = sTxt
                j = j + 1
            Else
                ' character count > 40
                brr = Split(sTxt, ",")
                sTmp = ""
                For k = 0 To UBound(brr)
                    If Len(sTmp) + Len(brr(k)) > 40 Then
                        ReDim Preserve res(0, 1 To j)
                        res(0, j) = Mid(sTmp, 2)
                        j = j + 1
                        sTmp = "," & brr(k)
                    Else
                        sTmp = sTmp & "," & brr(k)
                    End If
                Next
                If Len(sTmp) > 0 Then
                    ReDim Preserve res(0, 1 To j)
                    res(0, j) = Mid(sTmp, 2)
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' write back
    Cells(1, 1).Resize(j - 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(res)
End Sub
```

Option 2: Update for the requirement in comment

> If the column H cell data > 40 character count, insert a row in below and cut paste the data to the new cell, keep all data in column H < 40 character count.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim arr, i As Long
    Dim j As Long, sTxt As String
    Dim sTmp As String
    Dim iLoc As Integer
    ' Load data
    arr = Range([H1], Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)).Value
    For i = UBound(arr) To 2 Step -1
        sTxt = Trim(arr(i, 1))
        If Len(sTxt) > 40 Then
            j = 0
            sTmp = Left(sTxt, 41)
            Do While Len(sTmp) > 0
                If Len(sTmp) < 40 Then
                    Rows(i + j).Insert
                    Cells(i + j, "H") = sTmp
                    j = j + 1
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    ' Locate the last comma
                    iLoc = InStrRev(sTmp, ",") - 1
                    If j > 0 Then Rows(i + j).Insert
                    Cells(i + j, "H") = Left(sTxt, iLoc)
                    j = j + 1
                    ' Get the rest text, skip a comma
                    sTmp = Mid(sTxt, iLoc + 2)
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but looks like it's only handle the cell A1, if I have many rows, some data > 40 character count, some not, how to do it?

Comment: Is there any blank cell between data cells?  I have updated the code to make sure it catches all data in column A.

Comment: Yes, there is blank cells

Comment: Update the code to skip the blank cells.

Comment: Add a picture, column H is the data I want to edit.

Comment: I don't want to change the cells < 40 character count.

Comment: If the column H cell data > 40 character count, insert a row in below and cut paste the data to the new cell, keep all data in column H < 40 character count.

Comment: You should post final expected result, otherwise you have to adapt the code to get it done.

Comment: That looks good, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use a formula:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=LET(x,TOCOL(TEXTAFTER(","&A1:A2,",",SEQUENCE(,99,,8)),3),LEFT(x,39))
```

**Note**: This assumes your data follows the same pattern for each comma-delimited value.

A much more dynamic way would be:

```
=PY(
    import re
    sum([re.findall(r'(?:^|,)(.{0,39}[^,]\b)', x) for x in xl("A1:A2")[0]],[])
)
```

Where you'd have a regular expression to catch each substring that would be between delimiters and is a max of 40 characters long (greedy).

Answer (score 0):

Adding my 2c:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Const MAX_SIZE As Long = 12
    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet, v, cDest As Range, pos
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or some specific sheet
    Set cDest = ws.Range("B1")
    'loop over ColA
    For Each c In ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        v = c.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            Do
                pos = InStrRev(v, ",", MAX_SIZE)
                If pos = 0 Then
                    AddValue cDest, v
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    AddValue cDest, Left(v, pos - 1)
                    v = Mid(v, pos + 1, Len(v))
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

'populate a value and move one cell down
Sub AddValue(c As Range, v)
    c.Value = v
    Set c = c.Offset(1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Powerquery method, assumes nothing about the data except that items are separated by a comma

```
let Split = (Input)=> let  
a=List.Last(Input),
b = Text.Reverse(Text.AfterDelimiter(Text.Reverse(Text.Start(a&",",40)),","))
in List.RemoveLastN(if b="" then Input  else @Split2(List.FirstN(Input,List.Count(Input)-1) & {b} &  {Text.AfterDelimiter(Text.AfterDelimiter(a,b),",")}),1),

Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Output=    List.Combine(List.Transform(Source[Column1], each Split({_})))
in  Output
```

[image]